# Mysql convert 'CYYMM' to 'YYMM'

Tags: mysql, sql, date, load-data-infile, date-conversion

Suck with the following:

```
$loaddata = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' 
    INTO TABLE tb1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (
    Entity,
    HK,
    @Period,
    )
    SET Period = STR_TO_DATE(@Period,'%C%YY%MM')
    ";
```

which gives me and sql syntax error near

```
 ) SET Period = STR_TO_DATE(@Period,'%C%YY%MM')
```

Period is a DATE variable. for the period Oct-13 the cvs will show 11310.

tks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a few more example of the values you have?

Comment: August is month 8.  Your example appears to be month 10 (October)?  In any event, the format string is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a superfluous comma after `@Period`:

```
$loaddata = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv' 
    INTO TABLE tb1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (
    Entity,
    HK,
    @Period -- , removed here
    )
    SET Period = STR_TO_DATE(@Period,'%C%YY%MM')
    ";
```

However, your date format string is almost certainly incorrect.  `%C`, `%YY` and `%MM` are invalid specifiers.  See [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: tks!  I'm doing `SET Period = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(@Period,1),'%y%m')'"` and code runs w/o error but my Period columns shows only nulls. Is this bcs I'm uploading a DATE variable with just YYMM (missing day)?

Comment: @AMariani: Yes.  A `DATE` value must be an actual date (i.e. including day of the month).  Currently, MySQL does not know which day to assign: perhaps the first day of the month, perhaps the last, perhaps some other?  You can explicitly add your chosen day to `@Period` using `CONCAT()` (although if you simply append it then you can actually dispense with `STR_TO_DATE()` as the resulting string would already be a [valid date literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html)).

Comment: 'SET Period = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@Period,2),'01')' did the magic! tks!